# Typescript Filter a key value from array of objects

Tags: typescript

I have following array  of objects

```
var a: Array = [{ position: 3, name: "Lithium", weight: 6.941, … },{ position: 5, name: "Boron", weight: 10.811, … }{ position: 6, name: "Carbon", weight: 12.0107, … }]
```

I need a result array that will have the values of  'position' key

```
var resultArray = [3,5,6]
```

I need a method in typescript to get this resultant array .

Comment: Hi! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!) and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Answer (score 2):

```js
var resultArray = a.map(e => e.position)
```

Upon advice from Mathyn, I complete my answer with an explanation of how and why this solution works:

`Array.map()` executes a callback-function for every element of an array. The result of this map-call is an array of the results of the callback-calls.

[MDN web docs: Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: Your answer is correct but maybe it could be improved by explaining how and why this works.